# Delegate does not listen to the event

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

```
protocol NewHomeVCDelegate {
    func didEditHabit(_ habit: Habit)
}

class NewHomeVC: {
    var newHomeVCDelegate : NewHomeVCDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func didButtonTapped() {
        self.newHomeVCDelegate?.didEditHabit(habit)
        let vc = NewCreateHabitVC()
        
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

class NewCreateHabitVC: NewHomeVCDelegate {
    func didEditHabit(_ habit: Habit) {
        updateUI(habit: habit)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setViews()
        setDelegates()
        addGestureRecognizer()
        
        var newHomeVC = NewHomeVC()
        newHomeVC.newHomeVCDelegate = self 
    }

    func updateUI(habit: Habit) {
        // it does some stuff here
    }
}
```

I am trying to pass habit object from NewHomeVC to NewCreateHabitVC via delegate and protocol. However the problem is that the delegate does not listen. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: There's no need for a delegate in this setup. Delegates are useful for passing data back. But you need to pass data forward.

Comment: I think he needs the object back once editing is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are making this more complicate.
Here for what you need pass habit object from NewHomeVC to NewCreateHabitVC via delegate base on your code it send data to front screen vc i dont see a point of using that.

**NewHomeVC**

```
protocol NewHomeVCDelegate {
    func didEditHabit(_ habit: String)
}


class NewHomeVC: UIViewController {

let label : UILabel = {
    let label       = UILabel()
    label.text      = "Hello world"
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return label
}()


 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor =  .white
    
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    label.addGestureRecognizer( UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunction)))
    
    
}
    @objc
    func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        didButtonTapped()
    }

func didButtonTapped() {
    //you put it up here && wrong way of init the files

    let vc = NewCreateHabitVC()
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
    
    vc.newHomeVCDelegate?.didEditHabit("asdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs")
}
}
```

**NewCreateHabitVC**

```
class NewCreateHabitVC: UIViewController {

let label : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Hello world"
    return label
}()

var newHomeVCDelegate : NewHomeVCDelegate?


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
        
    self.setConstraint()
        
    newHomeVCDelegate = self
        
        
}
}



extension NewCreateHabitVC  : NewHomeVCDelegate {
    func didEditHabit(_ habit: String) {
            print(habit)
    }
}

extension NewCreateHabitVC {
    func setConstraint()  {
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

For delegate with protocol / completion. It more like send data backward to the caller screen.
What you need for pass to next screen vc :

**NewHomeVC**

```
    let vc = NewCreateHabitVC()
    vc.habbit = yourdata
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

**NewCreateHabitVC**

```
class NewCreateHabitVC : UIViewController {
.....
var habbit : your_data_type? = nil

......

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
struct Habit {
let name : String
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name = "name"
}
}

protocol NewHomeVCDelegate {
    func didEditHabit(_ habit: Habit)}

class NewHomeVC: UIViewController , NewHomeVCDelegate{

//var newHomeVCDelegate : NewHomeVCDelegate?

let myHabit = Habit(name: "I want to edit this habit")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

func didButtonTapped() {
    
    //no need here
    //self.newHomeVCDelegate?.didEditHabit(habit)
    
    //when you present the ViewController you the set the delegate, so he can ping you back once done. Also you need to set the object that you intend to edit
    let vc = NewCreateHabitVC()
    vc.newHomeVCDelegate = self
    vc.habitThatIwantToEdit = myHabit
    
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
}

//you have to implement this method in home class
func didEditHabit(_ habit: Habit) {
    //this object is the final edited object from NewCreateHabitVC, this will be called on finish button press, here you have it.
}
}


class NewCreateHabitVC: UIViewController, NewHomeVCDelegate {

//but here
var newHomeVCDelegate : NewHomeVCDelegate?

var habitThatIwantToEdit :Habit?

func didEditHabit(_ habit: Habit) {
    //
    //updateUI(habit: habit)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    //setViews()
    //setDelegates()
    //addGestureRecognizer()
    
    //var newHomeVC = NewHomeVC()
    //newHomeVC.newHomeVCDelegate = self
    
    if let _ = habitThatIwantToEdit{
        updateUI(habit: habitThatIwantToEdit!)
    }else{
        print("object not set")
    }
    
}


func updateUI(habit: Habit) {
    // it does some stuff here
    
}

func finishButtonTaped(){
    
    if let habit = habitThatIwantToEdit{
        newHomeVCDelegate?.didEditHabit(habit)
    }    
}
}
```